# Get the argument of python -m as is

Tags: python

A user of my framework supplies a custom script, which is run from the root folder of the framework, e.g.:

`python -m projects.user_project.script1`

I need to be able to run another user script from the same folder as the original one from within the framework (using `subprocess.check_output`). So, in the example, I might run `python -m projects.user_project.script2`.

How can I get the string `'projects.user_project'` in the example? I thought of getting it from `sys.argv`, but that contains the full absolute path to the original script.

Comment: Since Python 3.10, there is `sys.orig_argv` which would do what you asked. But instead of jumping through `subprocess` hoops, consider refactoring `script2` so that it can simply be imported as a module and called as a function.

Comment: @Thomas Is there a workaround to get to this information with an earlier version, e.g. Python 3.8?

Comment: Not that I know of. But like I said, ideally don't do this at all.